# UIPageViewController не до конца пролистывается пальцем вправо

Tags: objective-c, ios

Собственно говоря скрин:
[image: UIPageViewController не до конца пролистывается пальцем вправо]

Если прокрутить жестом обратно влево, все становится на место для следующего слайда. Фактически уйдя с 1го слайда, мы никогда не увидим его без бага вернувшись на него. 
Размер страницы правильный, ибо пальцем можно подвинуть картинку на место, но как только отпустим - снова возвращается в неверное положение. 
Отследить не могу, viewControllers возвращает массив из одного текущего элемента.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел причину. Причина: следующая страница перекрывала текущую, а т.к. элементы - изображения с выставленным свойством Aspect Fill, то соотвественно выходило за пределы свои и перекрывала текущую страницу.
Решение простое - выставление флага Clip Subviews изображению чтобы оно обрезалось, если выходит за область своего размера.

[image: Причина и решение проблемы]